# How does 9Gagtv removes the title of the embeded Youtube video?

Tags: html, youtube

How does 9gag.tv remove the title of the embeded Youtube video?

http://9gag.tv/v/1681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters):

> showinfo (supported players: AS3, AS2, HTML5) Values: 0 or 1. The
>   parameter's default value is 1. If you set the parameter value to 0,
>   then the player will not display information like the video title and
>   uploader before the video starts playing.
>
> If the player is loading a playlist, and you explicitly set the
>   parameter value to 1, then, upon loading, the player will also display
>   thumbnail images for the videos in the playlist. Note that this
>   functionality is only supported for the AS3 player since that is the
>   only player that can load a playlist.

If you want to do the same, you'll need to look into the cited page.